# No user/password boxes on login screen after updates today (June 30, 2012)

Tags: login-screen

Just installed today's batch of updates, including new kernel 3.2.0-26 and rebooted. Now the screen just has a logo in the middle and "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" in bottom left corner, but no box to choose which user to log in as, or to enter a password. CTRL-ALT-F1 gets me to a "login:" prompt, and I can log in - but I have no idea what to look at to find out what is wrong, or to fix this.

Tried older kernels and recovery mode for current kernel - no joy, still no way to log into the graphics console.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Switching login managers and or reinstalling Ubuntu? That is what I would do.

Comment: By "login manager" do you mean the display manager (which provides the login screen)?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly same problem as
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/993420

I didn't manage to get "screen speaking" turned on. But some random clicking did get the password box to appear. Things were still somewhat messed up as video settings seemed scrambled. But after more random clicking it sorted itself out - perhaps because something broken was reset when I downloaded some more updates? I have no idea.

Comment: It should be noted the bug linked here is marked as **Incomplete**, which means there is not enough information to reproduce the bug.  As such, unless that bug has additional activity within 8 days it'll be autoclosed by the system.